# How do I permanently disable Bluetooth in Ubuntu 17?

Tags: bluetooth

It defaults to being on in Ubuntu 17 which I can't change. If I switch off wifi it also automatically switches on. I don't want it on ever and am confused as to why they insist on it being on so much.